# Gradle assembleDebug and preDexDebug fail even for new project

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

i'm facing an error trying to compile an run my project. It even happens if I try to run a new project with just a blank activity in Android Studio.

The error occurs during the gradle 'preDexDebug' task.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/myname/Dev/tools/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/19.0.3/dx --dex --output      /Users/myname/Dev/products/MyApplication2/app/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-fd798db4dfad23fbf10ff420c899a156c7f9dc1e.jar /Users/myname/Dev/products/MyApplication2/app/build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.1.0/classes.jar
  Error Code: 1
```

Below my project configuration (tried both, online and offline mode):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fffQZ.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbGss.png

Anyone faced the same error?

**UPDATE**

If I manually run from the command line (project root folder)

```
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

The task runs and I'm again able to build and run the project on Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you got it to work, but just in case others have the issue and end up on this page like me - I was unable to kick start Android Studio into building again until I did a complete restart of the app.

I'm on Android Studio beta 0.8.1 on OSX mavericks.